# GWT 2.8.0 Validation: Cascading validation not evaluated

Tags: validation, gwt, hibernate-validator

I have this project:

```
public class A {
    @Valid
    private B b;
}

public class B {
    @Max(5)
    private int n;
}

public class ValidatorFactory extends AbstractGwtValidatorFactory {

    @GwtValidation({A.class, B.class})
    public interface GwtValidator extends Validator {}

    @Override
    public AbstractGwtValidator createValidator() {
        return GWT.create(GwtValidator.class);
    }
}

public class SomeWidget extends Widget {
    ...
    private A a;

    public void validate() {
        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<EgyenlegkozloModel>> violations = validator.validate(model);
    }
    ...
}
```

After running `SomeWidget.validate()`, even though `B.n` is higher than 5, a violation doesn't get generated. I checked the generated code and saw that the generator didn't generate the snippet that would validate the child.